# Anybody know of a free SDF file viewer?

Tags: sql

I have an SDF file and am looking for a free viewer to just view the db?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried SQL Server Management Studio Express [Browsing a .SDF file (SQL Server CE database file)](http://dotnetref.blogspot.com/2007/12/browsing-sdf-file-sql-ce-database-file.html)

Comment: You have to migrate them from Version 1 to Version 2 first.

Comment: i get incompatible database version, so i presume the sdf if older version so that's why im just looking for a simple free viewer

Comment: Erm how do i migrate them then?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172032.aspx and related documentation.

Comment: this doesnt work for me